# Translation Software

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Which software is best for translating Yu-gi-oh cards from Japanese to English without changing the original art.

[image: Japanese] [image: English]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translation software recommendations.

Comment: Can someone just answer me ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you looking to identify what a Japanese card is, given the clear inability to understand the name? Or are you looking to do something to cards that don't exist in English?

Comment: Im trying to edit the cards that dont exist in english

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic since 1) they have nothing to do with board or card games, 2) they are primarily opinion based, 3) they are specifically disallowed on the sister sites that do deal with software for numerous reasons.

Comment: Hello @Leopold, welcome to this site. I'm afraid this is not the best place to ask this question as we probably don't have the required expertise to give you a really helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps are needed

1. Erase the existing text. This is done by finding a card with little text and construct a square you can copy and paste over the existing text of the card you want to translate.
2. Add text.

Every single image manipulation program can perform those operations (copy, paste, move and add text), including MS Paint, a little plaything that comes with Windows.

Comment: Could you recommend a software ?

Comment: @Leopold, Any will do.